# "The program can't start because opencv_world300.dll is missing from your computer" error in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I want to compile an opencv Console C++ program in Visual Studio 2013. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Mat img = imread("rgb_1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

    if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
    imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

    waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

    return 0;
}
```

Although I have defined all the directories in properties both in Computer and Visual Studio directories, I get the following error:

> "The program can't start because opencv_world300.dll is missing from your computer."

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you have the dll in question, the easiest thing to do is copy and paste it into your projects executable output folder

Comment: I've noticed this dll is not placed with other dlls. You need to find out the folder in which `opencv_world300.dll` is located. That's all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Under windows you can copy it from:

```
<your install directory>\opencv30\build\x64\vc12\bin
```

And put it in your Visual Studio solution (I assume you are using a **x64/Release** configuration):

```
<your solution directory>\x64\Release
```

Or you you can add the above OpenCV to your PATH environment variable

Comment: It works and this is great, but I can't figure out why it worked flawlessy before <an unknown action of mine> without the present hack.

Comment: @RevJohn can you please explain how to do this: "And put it in your Visual Studio solution (I assume you are using a x64/Release configuration):

<your solution directory>\x64\Release"

Comment: Go into system environment variables and scroll down to the "Path" variable, edit it and add "<your install directory>\opencv30\build\x64\vc12\bin" to in (make sure to follow ; syntax and such).  Then restart visual studio and you should be set.

Comment: Even I faced this issue but it got solved by copying the dll, as I'm on a company PC and am not allowed edit the environment variables. Is copying the dll into the solution is the only way out for this issue if I cannot edit the environment variable?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

I'm on version `320`. Once all your environment variables are set make sure your `Additional Include Directories`, `Additional Library Directories` and `Additional Dependencies` are all correct. For me they were `$(OPENCV_BUILD)\include;`, `$(OPENCV_BUILD)\x64\vc14\lib;` and `opencv_world320d.lib;` respectively.

My `OPENCV_BUILD` path variable is `C:\opencv320\build` setting the environment variable to `%OPENCV_BUILD%\x64\vc14\bin` **(where the .dll files are located)**. To get to the `Additional` things right-click on your project/solution and select `properties -> C/C++` for the first and `properties -> Linker -> General` and `Input` for the other two.

**Restart Visual Studio** and if everything was implemented correctly then you should be able to run the program and it should start.

**Edit:**

Depending on what you used I had to also switch mine from `x86` to `x64` in the `Solution Platforms` dropdown.

Answer (score 7):

You can check your system variable to confirm the directory in which  `opencv_world300.dll` is located (maybe `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin`) is present.

If it exists but the problem still is not solved, try to put all `.dll` files in the directory to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`

Comment: Is the system variable is called `PATH` or are there others ? Does the name of the variable depend on the windows version ? What's the best way to read out the variable (example would be nice) ?

Comment: Suggesting to copy DLLs into the windows system directory is just terrible. Just set the `PATH` properly, instead of turning your OS into a mess.

Answer (score 5):

If this question is still relevant, I figured out the way.

I presume you used the tutorial on the `OpenCV` website to setup `OpenCV`. Once you run the command prompt and execute the command, it creates the environment variable for `OpenCV`but it does not add it in the path. So if you go to the path and add the location of the bin in vc12 (vc14 for me), save it, and restart visual studio, it works.

Answer (score 5):

I know this an old post but I noticed that mine has a problem distinguishing between `lib` and `bin`, so I added both to the PATH variable and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

After installing OpenCV version 3.4.1 for use with VS 2017 following [these instructions](https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-opencv-with-visual-studio/), Visual Studio complained about missing `opencv_world341d.dll`.  Even though I had added `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin` to the windows PATH, Visual Studio still couldn't find it as VS was already open when I modified the PATH.  Restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Best and simple solution is

1. Add path_variable of OpenCV/build/x64/bin in environment system variables.
2. And then restart the visual studio.

this definitely will solve the problem.

the problem might be you've updated the path variable after opening the visual studio so it can't update the *.dll files.

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio 2019,
TRY THIS
Add missing file opencv_world430.dll or opencv_worldd.dll in the debug directory of the project where your project application exe file is there.
copy & paste missing files in the debug folder

C:\Users\myname\source\repos\myopencv\x64\Debug + add your missing file here

my problem got solved in microsoft visual studio 2019 :)

Comment: I confirm. Although it sounds very cumbersome, but I don't care at this point. I just want this damn code to run right now :). Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem using version 320.
In my case my "Comodo Internet Security" was blocking a few things of the application itself and of OpenCV. Make sure to put them all on the "trusted" list by right clicking on them in your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Add the paths as everybody says and keep in mind to restart the Visual Studio.
 I added all the paths, even tried to copy all the *opencv_world.dll* in the same folder as the source file, all i had to do was to restart the Visual Studio after i added all the paths.

Answer (score 1):

This most commonly occurs when you do not add the file in question to your path variable **and** restart visual studio.

My `opencv_world460.dll` file was located in the following folder:
`C:\OpenCV-4.6.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin`. I added this to my system variables `PATH`.

Note in general, that when you update path variables, you must restart your console or visual studio. The path variables are only updated when you restart a console or when you restart visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded OpenCV from OpenCV 4.1.2 to 4.5.1 and it solved this problem (Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAD5A193D2 (opencv_world412d.dll))! The only Visual Studio setting change is the dll additional file name from opencv_world412d.dll to opencv_world451d.dll.