# opencv_world341d.dll was not found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, opencv3.0

I am trying to run OpenCV on Visual Studios 2017. I built the libraries and bin with CMake, so far it is working good. However, when I try to run the code it says this:

This is the error code message that shows when I launch the "local windows debugger":
[image: This is the error code message that shows when I launch the "local windows debugger"]

For some reason, it says that it can't find the DLL. I already assign the Aditional Dependencies in properties also I linked the "Included Directories" and "Included Libraries" to openCV in Visual Studios, the project is set to run in x64, and there are no errors on the programming it's just that error of DLL that shows.

The DLL can be found in a separate folder made by the compiler in a bin folder. However, it still says it can't be found.

This is the locations of the DLL files:
[image: This is the locations of the DLL files]

Is there a solution for this?

I tried to add pictures I'm new in the forum it doesn't let me post them yet. I am not sure if the ones I upload will show.

This is the code I tried to run and bring the error message. The same happen with any other code.

I will add more images that may help to understand what I did so far and thanks in advance for the help.

This are the Visual Studios C/C++ Directories:
[image: This are the Visual Studios C/C++ Directories]

This is the Linked section in Visual Studios properties:
[image: This is the Linked section in Visual Studios properties]

This is the environment PATH from Environment Variables:
[image: This is the environment PATH from Environment Variables]

This is all I did so far in the process to install OpenCV in Visual Studios.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat image;
    std::cout << "This image is" << image.rows << "X" << image.cols << std::endl;

    image = cv::imread("puppy.bmp");

    if (image.empty()) {

    }

    cv::Mat result;
    cv::flip(image, result, 1);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please share your makefile. most likely you didn't include the path to opencv libs in your LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick reply, I added the path if I'm not mistaking it was in Visual Studios properties. I also added the path in the Environment Variables. I was trying to upload more Images but it doesn't let me edit my post/

Comment: add it to your project's Library Directories. currently it only has "/path/to/opencv/lib". probably you need to add bin folder too.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was correct, I needed the bin folder too. How can I make your post the answer? This answer may help others also.

Comment: that's fine. they can read comments any how. or you can post the answer yourself.

Comment: Try the solution of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711093/the-program-cant-start-because-opencv-world300-dll-is-missing-from-your-comput/31721884

Answer (score 16):

For me, restart to Visual Studio solved the problem, I guess that's because when I added the OpenCV to Environment Variable the Visual Studio was open

Comment: It must be a joke to struggle with this problem until restarting

Answer (score 9):

Just copy opencv_world341d.dll to the x64 debug folder, and run it.
I also restart my computer after I add it to PATH. So the solution is just restart your computer when you add to PATH for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this issue and solved it simply by adding the OpenCV bin path to the environment variable.